Adjusting \textheight inside paracol environment
I am preparing the edition of a liturgical book with numerous bilingual areas (Latin-French). For these areas I use the paracol package.
It often happens that these areas are at the bottom of the page, and leave a widow-line on the next page. To remedy this I would like to use \enlargethispage, but this has no effect, because paracol has its own output-routine.
All other elements must remain as they are (font size, baselineskip, parskip, indent...) So is there a way to adjust \textheight inside paracol environment?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\batchmode%
\pretolerance=1500 \tolerance=3000 %
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=14.5cm, paperheight=20.5cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}%
\usepackage{fontspec} %
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[LocalForms=Off, Ligatures={Common,Historic,TeX},% 
    UprightFont=*-Regular, BoldFont=*-Bold, ItalicFont=*-Italic, BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,% 
    Extension=.otf]%
\usepackage{microtype}%
\usepackage[skip=2pt plus 0.2pt minus 0.2pt, indent=1em]{parskip}%
\usepackage[localmarks=true]{polyglossia} %
\setdefaultlanguage[frenchfootnote=true, frenchitemlabels=false, frenchpart=true]{french}% 
\setotherlanguage[variant=ecclesiastic, hyphenation=modern, usej=true]{latin}%
\usepackage{paracol}%
\columnsep=0.4cm%
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3pt}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\def\DirigaturVR{%
\vspace{5pt}%
\columnratio{0.47}%
\begin{paracol}{2}%
\switchcolumn[0]\setlength{\parskip}{-2pt}%
\normalsize\textlang{latin}{℣.~Dirigátur, Dómine, orátio mea.\par\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} ℟.~Sicut incénsum in conspéctu tuo.}%
\switchcolumn[1]\setlength{\parskip}{-2pt}%
℣.~Que ma prière, Seigneur, s'élève.\\\par\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} ℟.~En votre présence comme l'encens.%
\end{paracol}%
}%
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\lipsum[1-2]\par\lipsum[3][1-19]%
\enlargethispage{2mm}%
\DirigaturVR%
\bigskip%
\lipsum[1-2]%
%
\end{document}





With \newgeometry in the geometry package example10 p.17.

I tried with \newgeometry{paperwidth=14.5cm, paperheight=20.5cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}

Another possibility with \linespread{0.97} for \DirigaturVR (by manual test)

code
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\batchmode%
\pretolerance=1500 \tolerance=3000 %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=14.5cm, paperheight=20.5cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}%
\usepackage{fontspec} %
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[LocalForms=Off, Ligatures={Common,Historic,TeX},% 
    UprightFont=*-Regular, BoldFont=*-Bold, ItalicFont=*-Italic, BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,% 
    Extension=.otf]%
\usepackage{microtype}%
\usepackage[skip=2pt plus 0.2pt minus 0.2pt, indent=1em]{parskip}%
\usepackage[localmarks=true]{polyglossia} %
\setdefaultlanguage[frenchfootnote=true, frenchitemlabels=false, frenchpart=true]{french}% 
\setotherlanguage[variant=ecclesiastic, hyphenation=modern, usej=true]{latin}%
\usepackage{paracol}%
\columnsep=0.4cm%
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.3pt}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\def\DirigaturVR{%
\vspace{5pt}%
\columnratio{0.47}%
\begin{paracol}{2}%
\switchcolumn[0]\setlength{\parskip}{-2pt}%
\normalsize\textlang{latin}{℣.~Dirigátur, Dómine, orátio mea.\par\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} ℟.~Sicut incénsum in conspéctu tuo.}%
\switchcolumn[1]\setlength{\parskip}{-2pt}%
℣.~Que ma prière, Seigneur, s'élève.\\\par\setlength{\parskip}{2pt} ℟.~En votre présence comme l'encens.%
\end{paracol}%
}%
%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
% \newgeometry{paperwidth=14.5cm, paperheight=20.5cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}
\lipsum[1-2]\par
\lipsum[3][1-19]%
% \enlargethispage{2mm}%
\begingroup 
\linespread{0.97}
\DirigaturVR%
\endgroup

% \restoregeometry

\bigskip%
\lipsum[1-2]\par
\lipsum[3][1-19]%
\DirigaturVR%  without \linespread{0.97}
%
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer!
Indeed I had already tried the adjustment with \linespread which is locally helpful.
But I would like to understand why \newgeometry works and not \enlargethispage...
